# Trouble with icon picture when uploading app to app store

Tags: ios, icons, store

I have trouble uploading my application to app store. When I try to archive my project for validation i get an error:

> warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: BMELogo.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't
>   meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in
>   .png format (-19014) Unable to validate your application. - (null)

I have checked and re-checked my icon for both size and type. My icon is 57x57 and a PNG.
Do any of you know what to do?

in advance thanks :)

Comment: Try removing your current icon keys from your info.plist. Add them again, being doubly sure of case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird error, but it could be similar to what happens when apps on the phone don't match what you see in the simulator. Here's a few things to try:

1. As Damo mentioned, this is most likely a capitalization issue. Make sure that the filename as specified in the plist matches the case of what's on disk. Devices (and the app store) are case-sensitive, but your Mac is not. If it works in the simulator but not on device, you probably have a capitalization problem.
2. You might need to Clean (from the Build menu) the project and rebuild. Sometimes XCode just gets confused, especially if you've been moving or renaming images. Quitting & restarting XCode might help, too.
3. Nuke the site from orbit -- manually delete all of the project's output files. Sometimes XCode keeps old versions of image files around packaged somewhere hidden that cleaning doesn't get rid of.
4. Start over from scratch. Choose a different name, one where you're sure there's no legacy object file lingering about.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to make sure that you are using the latest version of the Application Loader, you can download the latest by logging into iTunes Connect and clicking on Manage Your Applications, the download is at the bottom of the page.

After you download the installer, close down Xcode, then run the Application Loader installer, then relaunch Xcode, load your project, do a clean on the project, and then archive and try the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too. You need to reinstall Application Loader which you can get from here https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg